# Laravel Foreign Key is changed to lowercase

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to access relation fields values and when i'm trying to do this 'i'm getting error :

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sub_areas.subarea_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`sub_areas`where`sub_areas`.`subarea_id`is null limit 1)`

I can't understand why it's change it to lower keys with underscore ;

Thank For Any Help.

**access the model:**

```
$subArea = City::find(1)->subArea;
```

And in Model the primary key is :

**City Model:**

```
/**
* Overriding default Primary Key
* @var string
*/
protected $primaryKey = 'SubAreaID';

public function subArea()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubArea::class);
}
```

**SubArea Model**

```
public function city()
{
     return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

**Migration :**

```
     Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('Id');
        $table->integer('AreaID')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('SubAreaID')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('CityID')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('Title', 50);
        $table->string('Latitude', 100);
        $table->string('Longitude', 100);            
        $table->tinyInteger('Active')->unsigned()->default(1);
    });
```

**Adding foreign keys:**

```
   Schema::table('cities', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('AreaID')
              ->references('AreaID')->on('areas')
              ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('restrict');

        $table->foreign('SubAreaID')
              ->references('SubAreaID')->on('sub_areas')
              ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('restrict');    
    });
```

And if i pass foreign key inside the function like this

**CityModel**

```
  return   $this->hasOne(SubArea::class, 'SubAreaID');
```

**SubArea Model**

```
  return $this->belongsToMany(\City::class, 'cities', 'SubAreaID');
```

I dont get any results to.
but this is one more question.

Comment: What model are you accessing the relationship from? Can you show the code for how you're trying to access the relationship?

Comment: i have edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the primary key of your `City` model is not `SubAreaID` according to your migrations. It is just `Id`. Assigning it to `SubAreaID` will in fact cause `find(1)` to look for a column where the `SubAreaID` is 1, which I do not believe is what you're trying to do.

Now, by default, when you define a `belongsTo` relationship, Laravel has a default naming convention.

> By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case"
>   name of the owning model and suffix it with _id.
>   http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

In this case, when you define `$this->belongsTo(SubArea::class)` in `City`, it will assume that you have a `subarea_id` column in the `City` model.

However, you may override this behavior by passing your custom key as the second argument.

```
public function subArea()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubArea::class, 'SubAreaID');
}
```

Similarly, in your `SubArea` model

```
public function city()
{
     return $this->hasMany(City::class, 'SubAreaID');
}
```

Finally, the last two relationship

> CityModel
>
> ```
> return   $this->hasOne(SubArea::class, 'SubAreaID');
> ```
>
> SubArea Model
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany(\City::class, 'cities', 'SubAreaID');
> ```

Won't work because that simply isn't how your tables were set up.

Comment: Thank you this is help bu why i got query like this? ` 'select * from `cities` where `cities`.`SubAreaID` is null and `cities`.`SubAreaID` is not null and `cities`.`Id` = ?'`  why it is setting where cities.SubArea is null?

Comment: @Victorino What is this query? When you do `City::find(1)->subArea;` or what?

Comment: yes . here is my model access - `$city = $sub->city()->where('cities.Id', 1)->get()->toArray();` and query that i get is currect except that is setting `SubAreaID is NULL` here is `select * from `cities` where `cities`.`SubAreaID` is null and `cities`.`Id` = ?` i cannot understand why

Comment: Because when you do `$sub->city()`, you are trying to find all the `City` that has a `SubArea`. This implies that `SubAreaID` cannot possibly be null. If `SubAreaID` is null, then the relationship is invalid.